# Combine multiple similar columns into single column

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like

```
Id    RefNumber     LotNum
---------------------------
1      Ref-1        10
2      Ref-1        11
```

**Lotnumber**:

```
Lot-Id    Lot-Name
-------------------
10         Apple
11        Banana
```

I need my output to look like this:

```
Ref-1    Apple,Banana
```

Please help me - how can I achieve this?

Comment: it does help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/how-to-concatenate-text-from-multiple-rows-into-a-single-text-string-in-sql-serv

Comment: What is your sql server version, and what compatibility version ?

Comment: Note that prasanna has linked to a question that has many hacks for what should now be done by group_concat if it is available..

Answer (score 1):

On SQL Server 2017 and later, we can use `STRING_AGG` here:

```
SELECT
    r.RefNumber,
    STRING_AGG(l.[Lot-Name]) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY l.[Lot-Id]) AS LotNames
FROM Refs r
LEFT JOIN Lotnumber l
    ON r.LotNum = l.[Lot-Id]
GROUP BY
    r.RefNumber;
```